# Starting my activity after phone unlocks

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to postpone my activity if the screen is locked. For example, if the screen is locked, I want to detect when the user unlocks the screen then start my activity right afterwards. This is what I am using currently to detect if its locked. but I can't seem to figure out how to start my activity right after its unlocked? Does KeyguardManager automatically update when the screen is unlocked? Thanks!

```
KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
 if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
 //it is locked
 else
 {
  //it is unlocked
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the behavior of KeyguardManager but I can offer you an alternative solution using a broadcast receiver.

In my app, I did the following:

1. Create new class that extends BroadcastReceiver
2. Register receiver in manifest and assign the following intent-filter:

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.the.phonagramtwo.UserPresentReciever" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
3. Define desired behavior following unlock in onRecieve method

   ```
   public class UserPresentReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           Activity a = new Activity;
           Intent i = new Intent(a.getBaseContext(), ActivityYouWithToStart.class);
           a.startActivity(i);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for this. Does this onReceive class automatically detect if the user unlocks it?

Comment: If it helps to think of it that way I guess that's OK but its not entirely accurate. I strongly recommend you read the following [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html). It's lengthy, dry, and downright boring but it explains a lot about this topic. Note the section on BroadcastReceivers.